# VB6 .dll get calling application path

Tags: dll, vb6

I'm making a .dll from VB6. I need to know the path of the application that will use that .dll, but I can't figure out how to do this **directly from the .dll**.. Anyone know how to do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

Well this seems to work as a DLL:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const API_NULL As Long = 0

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetModuleHandleA" ( _
    ByVal lpModuleName As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleBaseName Lib "psapi" _
    Alias "GetModuleBaseNameA" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Long, _
    ByVal hModule As Long, _
    ByVal BaseName As String, _
    ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleFileNameEx Lib "psapi" _
    Alias "GetModuleFileNameExA" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Long, _
    ByVal hModule As Long, _
    ByVal FileName As String, _
    ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function ExeBaseName() As String
    Dim Size As Long

    ExeBaseName = Space$(256)
    Size = GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), _
                             GetModuleHandle(API_NULL), _
                             ExeBaseName, _
                             256)
    ExeBaseName = Left$(ExeBaseName, Size)
End Function

Public Function ExeFileName() As String
    Dim Size As Long

    ExeFileName = Space$(256)
    Size = GetModuleFileNameEx(GetCurrentProcess(), _
                               GetModuleHandle(API_NULL), _
                               ExeFileName, _
                               256)
    ExeFileName = Left$(ExeFileName, Size)
End Function
```

Calling the appropriate method gets the base name or full file name of the main program.