# Vb6 code to get calling aspx path information

Tags: asp.net, dll, vb6

I am importing a vb6 dll in asp.net web page.
If imported in windows application(exe), I was able to get calling application physical path from vb6 dll using code as mentioned in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591408/vb6-dll-get-calling-application-path),

Code:

```
 Dim Size As Long

ExeFileName = Space$(256)
Size = GetModuleFileNameEx(GetCurrentProcess(), _
                           GetModuleHandle(API_NULL), _
                           ExeFileName, _
                           256)
ExeFileName = Left$(ExeFileName, Size)
```

how to get same if calling application is aspx webpage?

Now it returns path as,

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe"
```

Comment: There is no "importing" of a VB6 dll. There is no "calling application" too. What this function does is get the executable filename of the current process. Unfortunately there is no associated "running aspx page" with current process so what you want to do is impossible not only in VB6 but in .Net too. If you find a .Net solution post it here and someone will translate it to VB6.

Comment: I suspect that if you describe _why_ you are trying to retrieve the calling's application path (or website for that matter), e.g. for storing the calling page in a log, someone will come up with a different suggestion on how to approach this.

Comment: You might be able to do this, but VB6 is limited to x32 bits, and most web servers these days are running as x64 bits. you can't mix in-process x32 and x64 bit code. As a result, you have to force the site to run as x32 bits. I would take the vb6 source file if you have, and convert to vb.net code if at all possible here.

Comment: VB.NET would still report w3wp.exe as the executable, because that's the worker process executing the ASP.NET file. The thing is: the concept of "parent process" doesn't make much sense for a web application. It's technically the "right answer", but the "question" _(=utilizing GetModuleFileNameEx)_ was wrong. That's why I asked for the actual purpose of the question/that operation.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal there is actually some method of using an out of process 32bit COM DLL from a 64 bit process.